# Prestashop delete products from specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

So I'm trying to import new products to my webshop, but I really need to delete 9000 products from a specific ID to the last one. Also, would be really nice if the method will delete the pictures associated to the products.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data and the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is based on this answer [[SOLVED] Delete massive products from database (10420 products)](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/609319-solved-delete-massive-products-from-database-10420-products/).

I just added the condition `` WHERE `id_product` BETWEEN 666 AND 9666 ``. You should put your lower and upper bounds there. The code deletes 1000 products at each run to avoid timeouts.

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php');

$res = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_product` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` WHERE `id_product` BETWEEN 666 AND 9666 ORDER BY `id_product` DESC LIMIT 1000 ');
echo "<p>(".date('Y/m/d H:i:s').") Starting to delete products...</p>";
if ($res) {
    foreach ($res as $row) {
        echo "<p>(".date('Y/m/d H:i:s').") Deleting product with ID <b>".$row['id_product']."</b>...";
        $p = new Product($row['id_product']);
        if(!$p->delete()) {
            echo " <span style='color: red'>Error deleting this product!</span></p>";
        } else {
            echo " <span style='color: green'>DELETED</span></p>";
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
window.location.reload();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution since Prestashop saves product information in multiple tables, not only ps_product.

Comment: We use table `ps_product` only to get ids. Then we execute Prestashop's `Product->delete()` to delete images and data from all tables.